# Quilljs toolbar

Tags: angularjs, quill

I have the issue with creating toolbar dynamically.
The code is the next:

```js
$onChanges (bind) {
    if (bind.selected.currentValue) {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.quill = new Quill(`#editor-${this.component.id}`, {
                theme: 'snow',
                modules: {
                    toolbar: `#toolbar-container-${this.component.id}`
                },
                placeholder: 'Put some text here'
            });
        }, 1);
    } else {
        this.quill = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="{{'editor-' + vm.component.id}}"></div>

<div ng-show="vm.component" id="{{'toolbar-container-' + vm.component.id}}">
  <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-font">
          <option selected>Sans Serif</option>
          <option value="inconsolata">Inconsolata</option>
          <option value="roboto">Roboto</option>
          <option value="mirza">Mirza</option>
          <option value="arial">Arial</option>
      </select>
      <select class="ql-size"></select>
  </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
  </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-color"></select>
      <select class="ql-background"></select>
  </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
      <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
  </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-align"></select>
  </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-clean"></button>
  </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-link"></button>
      <button class="ql-image"></button>
      <button class="ql-video"></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

The #editor and the #toolbar NODES is in the different components.

And i create new instance of the Quill on focus the component.

As well i do it for creating multiple instances of editor and use the toolbar in the single other place.

But on focusing on the editor I got the error

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at IconPicker.selectItem (quill.js:9444)
    at new IconPicker (quill.js:9435)
    at eval (quill.js:6569)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SnowTheme.buildPickers (quill.js:6564)
    at SnowTheme.extendToolbar (quill.js:9602)
    at SnowTheme.addModule (quill.js:6533)
    at eval (quill.js:5443)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SnowTheme.init (quill.js:5441)
```

And when I try to add the new editor then i got the same error message.

Please provide me with the info, what I am doing wrong? 
Will appreciate any help about quilljs.

Comment: Are you using quill from the cdn or a custom build?

Comment: @jhchen, I'm using quill as npm package and it's built with webpack

Comment: Okay make sure you are following this guide: https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/. It sounds like maybe the html-loader is not being used so the icons are not being built. Otherwise please post your webpack.config.js.

Comment: @jhchen I'm getting this same error with an Angular project. It works fine on initial load, but whenever a component is destroyed and reinitialized this error pops up. The toolbar is a separate HTML component. It works fine with version 1.2.6, but not with 1.3.0. This is the change that causes the error: github.com/quilljs/quill/pull/1576/files.

Comment: @jhchen I just noticed that multiple instances of Quill are being created.  There's a HTML toolbar on top, and the content below changes (when a different page layout is selected, for example) which creates another instance anytime a layout is changed.  How would I destroy an instance of the editor?

Comment: @jhchen Here's a codepen of a similar situation: https://codepen.io/Folkman/pen/brPrZr?editors=1010#0 When you format text you cannot unformat it and the console states "The given range isn't in document."  I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong.